# audio plays only with one image

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, android

I am working on an Android app in which I am implementing the ff-mpeg features to convert images into video and then using that video to merge audio in its background.
But the problem is this when audio merged successfully, it's only play with one image not with all images in video.
Can anyone help me?
Here is my code:

```
fun mergeAudioVideo(inputVideo: String, inputAudio: String, output: String): Array<String> {
    val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    inputs.apply {
        add("-i")
        add(inputVideo)
        add("-i")
        add(inputAudio)
        add("-filter_complex")
        add("[0:a]volume=0.15,apad[A];[1:a][A]amerge[Aout]")
        add("-c:v")
        add("copy")
        add("-map")
        add("0:v")
        add("-map")
        add("[Aout]")
        add("-y")
        add("-shortest")
        add("-preset")
        add("ultrafast")
        add(output)
    }
    return inputs.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(inputs.size))
}
```

I copy this command from ffmpeg mobile library available on github:
https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSffmpegVideoOperation

Comment: Welcome to SU. Unfortunately this is [off topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in SU. When you join a new SE community, you should check the Asking and Answering -questions in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how that site works, what's required for questions etc. As this is a coding question, it might belong to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)l; but then again this is Android-specific so it might belong to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Before posting have a look at the Help on both sites to see in which one this is on topic.

Comment: Note that app development question is off-topic on [Android.SE], though if the underlying question is purely about FFmpeg and not the coding itself, then it may be on-topic.